# RequestParam with map is unnecessarily binding other request params in GET request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller, request-mapping

I have a GET request like this :-

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/foo")
          public Model getSomething(
          @RequestParam(value = "a", required = true) String a,
          @RequestParam(value = "b") String b,
          @RequestParam(value = "c") int c,
          @RequestParam Map<String, String> map) { 

}
```

The problem is when I make get request a,b,c gets included in map.
I have used mapping like this:-

**/foo?a=A&b=B&c=100&key1=value1&key2=value2**

Currently what is happening is map is having all the request param values. For eg

a-"a"

b-"b"

c-100

key1-value1

key2-value2

The requirement is to have map with only key1 and key2 as keys.
I want to use map to extract key1 and key2 only.
How can this be achieved.

Comment: are the keys known or will they be different all the time?

Comment: @ChrisSavory keys of map may be different

Comment: This is how Spring handles a `@RequestParam Map` parameter, there's no configuration to exclude params mapped to another argument, I'm afraid. You could probably use AOP with an around aspect, if you're really bent on not removing keys from the map manually and you want it for more than one request mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't exclude params for the `@RequestParam` map.

Do your client have the option to send those params with the body as a json object instead of as request parameters?  A request body isn't normally sent in GET Requests, but you could do it. Then you would change `@RequestParam<String, String> map)` to `@RequestBody Map<String, String> map)`